# Concatenating a string with part of another string in Python

Tags: python, concatenation

Problem:

I have a csv file with partial city names in one column (usually missing the first one or two letters), and another column in the same file, that has other information and often contains the one or two missing letters in the end of that string.

e.g.
Column 1
w York

Column 3
word word Ne

My logic on how to approach this problem is to have a separate CSV file with valid city names, and perform the Python version of a VLOOKUP pre and post concatenation, so that it only concatenates if it does not already match with valid city data.

I am stuck on how to actually pull one or two characters from the end of a string in column 3 (substring, but repeatedly down a column) and merge it with the start of a string in column 1, but I already know how to execute the rest of my idea.

Here is a general script for concatenation using Pandas:

```
pd.concat([col1, col2.set_axis(col1.index[-len(col2):], inplace=False)], axis=1)
```

Would the addition of a -2 resolve the issue? i.e.

```
pd.concat([col1, col2.set_axis(col1.index[-len(col2)-2:], inplace=False)], axis=1)
```

Thank you!

Comment: You will get more and better answers if you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.  Especially make sure that the input and expected test data are complete (not pseudo-data), and can be easily cut and and paste into an editor to allow testing proposed solutions.

Comment: How are you planning to parse the CSV file? Pandas? stdlib `csv` module? Something else? If you're using `csv` module, "repeatedly down a column" just means "for each row". Inside the usual `for row in csv.reader(infile):` loop, you can do `row[1] = row[1][:2] + row[3]` or whatever you want, and then you pass that to `writer.writerow(row)` the same as usual.

Answer (score 0):

If you decide on Pandas, after loading the csv into a pandas dataframe, you can extract the last 1 or 2 characters from column 3 this way and prepend it to column 2 this way:

```
df_city_names['col3'].map(lambda x: "".join(str(x)[-(2 if len(str(x)) > 1 else 1 if len(str(x)) > 0 else ''):])) + df_city_names['col2']
```

Comment: Thank you. Is that line self-iterative, or would I need to include it as part of a for loop, so that it does this for each row?

Comment: Hi! It is self iterative. It 'maps' each row of df_city_names['col3'] with this lambda.

Comment: Hi, I have written up some sample code but it is too long to post as a comment. So to be brief, does the map function you have written actually update column 2, or does it only print out a prepended version as an output? You mentioned that I would need to import the csv as a pandas dataframe beforehand, which I have done. Would the map function have prepended the information stored in the dataframe, or the csv, etc? It is relevant to the vlookup and writing the  output to the file after this 'map' step.

Comment: Hi! It doesn't update it. It only prints it. You can either store it as a separate column, by adding df_city_names['col4'] = to its left, or update col3 by adding df_city_names['col3'] =

Comment: Also, I saw that you edited the question. Please note that pandas.concat will not create a merged column by appending each of the values together in the parameter columns passed. It rather 'cbind's or 'rbind's them. So unless 'cbind' is your objective, pd.concat is not what you need.